# Reading out a Macbook Pro 2013 (A502) SSD

Tags: macbook-pro, ssd

My Macbook Pro 2013 has unfortunately met its demise after many years of service. I would like to access the data stored on its SSD, but I don't know the best way to go about it. The devices I have available are a standard PC (Linux/Windows) and a Macbook Pro 2020.

I have removed the SSD successfully from the MBP 2013, but due to the connectors, I cannot easily connect it to any hardware I have available.

What adaptor do I need?

Comment: Did you try accessing it in [Target Disk Mode](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/mchlp1443/mac)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find an external enclosure here : https://eshop.macsales.com/item/OWC/MAU3ENVOYPRO/